# navigation without map?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [navigation tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) says that
"The navigation stack does not require a map to operate".

What it will do?

Does it mean that robot just avoid any obstacles but unknown where it is?

or it means navigation use static map not dynamic map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10482/navigation-without-map?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The navigation stack does not require an *a priori* static map to operate.

That tutorial is referring to the fact that you can set both the global and local costmaps to use rolling windows, effectively removing the need for an *a priori* map.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-05**:
You cannot ignore the costmaps - those are what aggregate sensor data for use by planning. Without them, you won't avoid obstacles! Static map vs. rolling window is basically just whether to seed the costmap with the a priori map (and have a fixed origin) or a small rolling window centered on the robot. Both of those options will have the configured sensors used to aggregate obstacle information.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-05**:
So can I say if I use gmapping, I can ignore global & local costmaps?  By the way, is costmap a priori static map? in your reply seems not...

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-31**:
So this would mean running the navigation stack without gmapping or amcl? And that in this case the transform map->odom doesn't exist?

So then in what frame should the robot be given goals to navigate to? odom?

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-09-05**:
I'm interested to this topic too. any news?

**Comment by [nightblue](https://answers.ros.org/users/23339/nightblue/) on 2015-10-06**:
to @2ROS0 : That does not mean navigate without AMCL. You will need AMCL anyway (but not gmapping).

My question is that: I have a priori map and I want to use it  thru navigation. Sould I use "static map: true and rolling_window: false" in both local and global costmaps?

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2015-11-09**:
@2ROS0 , i think when  running navigation without static map ,it doesn't need AMCL(AMCL is meant for localization only (based on a known map) and will not work with a non-static map).If you set fixed frame is odom, the goal is given in odom ,maybe its localization error is big.

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2015-11-09**:
@2ROS0 ,when you set fixed frame is map,you need SLAM  like gmapping  to publish the tree from map to odom , i think its localization error is smaller.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2015-11-18**:
@nightblue you're right - I figured that out, this thread is a bit outdated.
As for your question - the normal trend is to use rolling_window: true for local costmap since by definition that map is used for collision checking with the immediate robot.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2015-11-18**:
@nightblue so I would leave the global costmap as static and keep a rolling window for the local costmap unless you have a specific reason to diverge from this method.

**Comment by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on 2016-02-02**:
@nightblue and @2ROS0 so whats the conclusion!? I do not want to use a map. So do i need to configure amcl or not? And do i need map->odom-> base_link -> laser or odom-> base_link -> laser is fine?